# Find if a string contains number sequences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to come up with a query that can determine if there is a number sequence of 3 or more numbers within a string (varchar). This is for SQL Server

Example string: "521324567"
This row of data would be returned because it has a sequence of "4567".

Example string: "410747823"
This row of data will not be returned because there is no sequence of 3 or more numbers.

Example string: "1274563619"
This row of data will be returned because it has the sequence "456".

I think I could probably figure something out similar to the sql below if it were a fixed length string.

```
Select num from numbers where substring(num,2,1)=
(select substring(num,1,1)) + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only 7 possible sequences, so:

```
select num
from numbers
where num like '%123%'
   or num like '%234%'
   or num like '%345%'
   or num like '%456%'
   or num like '%567%'
   or num like '%678%'
   or num like '%789%'
```

If you count `012` then you can add a condition for that too.

Comment: nice logic, but still excite to see by other logical query.

Comment: +1 for visiting the row source only once. I'd be interested in knowing if `charindex` would result in fewer machine instruction executions than `like`. Some (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543831/1707353) seem to think so.

Comment: @jeff I doubt using `charindex` instead would make a measureable difference

Answer (score 1):

try This. I Know it's a little complex. But Works Dynamic

```
DECLARE @MyNum NVARCHAR(50) = '1274563619'

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       SeqNo = 1,
       MyNum = @MyNum,
       PosNum = SUBSTRING(@MyNum,1,1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       SeqNo = SeqNo +1,
       MyNum,
       PosNum = SUBSTRING(MyNum,SeqNo,1)
       FROM CTE
          WHERE SeqNo <= LEN(@MyNum)
)
SELECT
    MyNum
    FROM CTE C1
       WHERE EXISTS
       (
          SELECT 1 FROM CTE C2
             WHERE 
                (
                    C2.SeqNo = C1.SeqNo+1 
                    AND
                    C2.PosNum = C1.PosNum+1
                )
                OR
                (
                    C2.SeqNo = C1.SeqNo+2 
                    AND
                    C2.PosNum = C1.PosNum+2
                )
       )
       GROUP BY MyNum
          HAVING COUNT(1)>2
```

Answer (score 0):

Bohemian is correct but here's a variation for a select list:

```
select num, case when 
   num like '%012%'
   or num like '%123%'
   or num like '%234%'
   or num like '%345%'
   or num like '%456%'
   or num like '%567%'
   or num like '%678%'
   or num like '%789%'
   or num like '%890%'
   or num like '%901%' 
then 'Yep' else 'Nope' end as is_there_a_sequence
from numbers
```

I also added `012` and `890`.  Though `901` may be a bridge too far.

I hope this helps.